# What is transcriptMode of an Android ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

What is transcriptMode of an Android ListView?
What does it do?

Comment: When you read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode), what did you learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

"In transcript mode, the list scrolls to the bottom to make new items visible when they are added."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode

EDIT:  To clarify, the above link is AbsListView,  the super class of ListView, where the attribute comes from.

Comment: but thats AbsListView. is the normal ListView an extension of AbsListView?

Comment: AbsListView is the super class of ListView.  It inherits the attribute, so if you select the attribute from the ListView documentation page, it redirects to AbsListView.
Edit: changed fieldto attribute..